# MVC upgrade of JQuery to 2.0.2 causing errors Object [object Object] has no method 'dialog' and 'accordion'

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application that uses bundles I am trying to upgrade JQuery version 2.0.2 from 1.9.1  but I cant seem to get the application to run.

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
  //"~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js",
  "~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js",
  "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryvalidate").Include(
  "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js",
  "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"));
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
  //"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.2.js"
  "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"));
```

I tried upgrading jquery.unabtrusive-ajax.js to version 3.0.0 via NuGet but this failed got the error below:

```
Updating 'jQuery 1.9.1' to 'jQuery 1.5.1' failed. Unable to find a version of      'jQuery.UI.Combined' that is compatible with 'jQuery 1.5.1'.
```

I have looked to see if more that one JQuery Library is getting loaded in but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: This not looks fine for me: Updating 'jQuery 1.9.1' to 'jQuery 1.5.1'
Are you downgrading jQuery?

Comment: no I am wanting to upgrade to 2.0.2 from 1.91 but I thought Microsoft Jquery Unobtrusive Ajax was causing the issue so went in to nuget updates and it said an update was available and it was but this failed

Answer (score 0):

I think Jquery UI plugins are missing.Actually you are downgrading from 1.9.1 to 1.5.1.So in 1.9.1 these plugins are automatically included once you include jquery js file in your code.While if you are downgrading then you need to include  the respective plugin's.Also make sure that the plugin that you are adding should support 1.5.1 version.